# Get values of checked radio button with post request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, ecmascript-6, backend

I have a few radio buttons a user can check to add search parameters to their search query. When I make the post request to my server, I am getting 'on' as the value.

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="radio" name="sushi">
  <label for="sushi">Sushi</label>
  <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
     const request = req.body;
     let sushi = request.sushi;

    console.log(sushi); //returns 'on'
});
```

I can get the value from a text input field using this method with no problem, but the radio buttons do not work this way. They only return a value of `on` if the radios are clicked on submit. I know I am missing something, but I'm having trouble finding any solutions that don't relate to the frontend and JQuery.

How can I pass the value of these checked buttons to my backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a value property on your radio input:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="radio" value="sushi" name="sushi">
  <label for="sushi">Sushi</label>
  <button type="submit">Enter</button>
</form>
```

this is what gets posted

Comment: Great thank you. For whatever reason I was thinking since the label was attached to the input name that the input would hold the label value.